# C string manipulating (cutting some special char* tail)

Tags: c

Why here I cannot get "cd fjadf"?
And the program always shows me a `Bus error: 10...`

I want to use this `super_cut_tail()` function to cut off `///fjdakf`, which is assigned by the user. 
But why this function cannot achieve that?

```
char* super_cut_tail(char *char_arg, char *special) {
    char *special_ptr;
    special_ptr = strstr(char_arg, special);
    int len = (int)strlen(char_arg) - (int)strlen(special_ptr);
    char_arg[len] = '\0';
    char_arg = strdup(char_arg);
    return char_arg;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char *test = "cd fjadf///fjdakf";
    char *outcome;
    outcome = super_cut_tail(test, "///");
    printf("test: %s\n", test);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using Xcode, and it is the C program.

Comment: Please remove c++ tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior since you are modifying the string that was used to initialize `test`. When you use:

```
char *test = "cd fjadf///fjdakf";
```

`"cd fjadf///fjdakf"` is held in read-only memory of the program. Modifying that string, which you are doing in the line

```
char_arg[len] = '\0';
```

is cause for undefined behavior.

Use:

```
char test[] = "cd fjadf///fjdakf";
```

The other thing you could do is use:

```
char const* test = "cd fjadf///fjdakf";
```

and make a copy of the string first in `super_cut_tail` before you attempt to modify it.

```
char* super_cut_tail(char const* char_arg, char *special) {
    char* ret_string = strdup(char_arg);
    char *special_ptr;
    special_ptr = strstr(ret_string, special);
    int len = (int)strlen(ret_string) - (int)strlen(special_ptr);
    ret_string[len] = '\0';
    return ret_string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Learned that!

Comment: Why are you using const? Can the program run without const?

Comment: When you use `char const*`, the compiler won't let you modify the string. SInce you are making a copy by calling `strdup`, it's ok to pass a `char cosnt*` to `super_cut_tail`..

Comment: You said that _char*_ is in the read-only memory. Why here I can change the content of _ret_string_ by using _ret_string[len] = '\0';_? Is that because of _strdup()_?

Comment: @JasonSmith, when you use it in an application, you have to remember to call `free()` on the pointer that was returned by `strdup`. In your case, you have to use `free(outcome);` after you are done using `outcome`.

Comment: Thus if I write the code like this: `char* ret_string = "1234"; ret_string = strdup(ret_string);` Can I make it editable by this way?

Comment: It will be better to use `char const* s1 = "1234"; char* ret_string = strdup(s1);` Make the variable that is initialized using a string literal a `char const*` or an array of `char`,

Comment: In this case, thus I need to `free(ret_string)`, is that right?

Comment: God... There are some many things that I learned behind the scene! Thank you

Comment: Is there any difference between `char* xxx` and `char *xxx`?

Comment: @JasonSmith, no, there isn't.